# Preserve links between copy-pasted Microsoft Word docs

Tags: microsoft-word

How do I keep links functional between two Word Docs that are saved in the same folder, but that folder is regularly copied and pasted and given a new name?  The documents always stay together, but the copied folder moves and is renamed...

Comment: Can you clarify what type of links you are talking about? Hyperlinks to bookmarks?